# Inverse of a Matrix in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-inverse

While trying to compute inverse of a matrix in python using `numpy.linalg.inv(matrix)`, I get singular matrix error. Why does it happen? Has it anything to do with the smallness of the values in the matrix. The numbers in my matrix are probabilities and add up to 1.

Comment: If the matrix has a determinant of 0 then it doesn't have a multiplicative inverse. The fact that all the values are small doesn't imply that the determinant will be 0. Check the determinant of your matrix and see if it's 0.

Comment: What does `numpy.linalg.det(your_matrix)` return?

Comment: Singular matrix is a matrix where two rows or two columns are perfectly linearly correlated, you cannot invert such matrix. As pointed out by others an easy way to check if a matrix is singular is to test whether the determinant is zero. My guess would be that either two rows or two columns in your matrix are exactly the same.

Comment: @Blender, see the error message::                                                              Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 445, in inv
    return wrap(solve(a, identity(a.shape[0], dtype=a.dtype)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 328, in solve
    raise LinAlgError, 'Singular matrix'
numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: Singular matrix

Comment: @Riyaz, your matrix likely has a determinant of zero, meaning it's a singular matrix. It has nothing to do with the size of the values. You can have small or large values and still get a determinant of 0.

Comment: @mbratch,  Its nan actually not zero when I get singular matrix error. I just checked for one instance, my data is huge and takes time to process, so i tested on some 20 points.

Comment: But when you convert to percentages (multiply the matrix by 100, as you say in your comment to an answer below) everything works fine?

Comment: @Akavall, not always, since em is initialized randomly, in some runs things go fine, when I use percentages which is not the case with probabilities.

Comment: In another run, though determinant is 5.13728826929e-22 (almost zero), had the same singular matrix error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may very well have to do with the smallness of the values in the matrix.

Some matrices that are not, in fact, mathematically singular (with a zero determinant) are totally singular from a practical point of view, in that the math library one is using cannot process them properly.

Numerical analysis is tricky, as you know, and how well it deals with such situations is a measure of the quality of a matrix library.

Comment: Thanks Dent. I guess its because of small values as you pointed out. I tried changing probabilities into percentages it works a few times (I am using em to cluster my data with dimensions of scaled to 1). Is their any other library in python that can fix this?

Comment: You could have a matrix with very large values and still be singular. It has nothing to do with the size of the values in the matrix unless they were so small that the computations in the computer made some non-zero results indistinguishable from zero.

Comment: That is fine, I know that singular matrix can't be inverted. My question is why is it happening. Why my matrix is a singular one. Is it because I use probabilities? That is what I want to know.

Comment: There are several possibilities for why it is happening.  One is that the matrix challenges the numerical capabilities of the system.  Computer arithmetic such as is used for heavy matrix manipulation is not exact, and rounding errors can blow you away when the magnitudes of the numbers are problematic or the matrix is close to singular, even if it is not totally singular.  It is also possible there is an error in the construction of the problem such that the matrix really is, in fact, singular, mathematically.  Using probabilities is NOT a problem in and of itself.

Comment: One more thing:  if you are trying to compute the inverse of a matrix in order to solve a linear system, DON'T.  It's basically the most difficult way to do it, from a practical point of view.  Any sufficiently advanced math package will have much better ways of accomplishing this.

Comment: @Arthur, I need inverse of a matrix, to compute the Gaussian distribution function of a random variable. what options do I have?

Comment: If a matrix is singular, does it imply that its covariance matrix will be singular too.

Comment: @Riyaz, yes in normal case it does, but I don't know about your case with tiny floats.